# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

I haven't used jQuery before, and I wanted to use `DateTimePicker` plugin on my web page.

I downloaded the plugin file and placed them in the same directory as the HTML files.

I directly applied the code at `How to use it?` in http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/.

It threw the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function pixelcrawler:61 (anonymous function)

My code follows.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="file:///jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>${conf['title']} <small>${conf['description']}</small></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
      <input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
                                        .
```

I could not figure out what the problem was. I have tried many other seemingly likely options, but it just did not work either.

(The ${} tags are used for the `Mako` template language. I am using `Cherrypy`.)

---

UPDATE:

I figured out the source of the problem.

It's from `jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();`.

When tested, the `datetimepicker()` function was undefined. Maybe the way I imported the library was wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery not working in external JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079811/jquery-not-working-in-external-js)

Comment: how come is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: See this answer, and try it. I'm pretty sure that it is your problem. so my comment says "Possible" I'm not saying it's a exacly duplicate.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
})
```

I don't know your file-structure. I never include local files like this as I use relative URLs from the start rather than having to change everytime I'm ready to use the code, but it's likely one of the files isn't being loaded in. I've included the standard datepicker below using Google [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)'s [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI). Does your console log any resources not found?

I think your jQuery is loaded OK, because it's not telling you jQuery is not defined so it's one of your files.

BTW, PHP gets the home URL:

```
$home="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
```

Demo code datepicker, jQuery UI:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    })
</script>

<input id="datetimepicker" type="text">
```

Comment: Make sure that you escape $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].  If it can't be pulled from the Vhost configuration the Host: HTTP header may be passed unfiltered to the script opening a few vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 17):

This is about the HTML parse mechanism.

The HTML parser will parse the HTML content from top to bottom. In your script logic,

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker')
```

will return an empty instance because the element has not loaded yet.

You can use

```
$(function(){ your code here });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function(){ your code here });
```

to parse HTML element firstly, and then do your own script logics.

Answer (score 14):

use jQuery.noConflict()

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
j(document).ready(function(){
    j('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
})
```

Answer (score 5):

For my situation, it was a naming conflict problem. Adding $J solves it.

```
//Old code:
function () {
    var extractionDialog;

    extractionDialog = $j("#extractWindowDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "form",
        height: "100",
        width: "250",
        modal: true
    });

    $("extractBomInfoBtn").button().on("click", function () {
        extractionDialog.dialog("open");
    }
```

And the following is new code.

```
 $j(function () {
    var extractionDialog;

    extractionDialog = $j("#extractWindowDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "form",
        height: "100",
        width: "250",
        modal: true
    });

    $j("extractBomInfoBtn").button().on("click", function () {
        extractionDialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Hope it could help someone.

Answer (score 4):

Usually when you get this problem, it happens because a script is trying to reference an element that doesn't exist yet while the page is loading.

As richie mentioned: "The HTML parser will parse the HTML content from top to bottom..."

So you can add your JavaScript references to the bottom of the HTML file. This will not only improve performance; it will also ensure that all elements referenced in your script files have already been loaded by the HTML parser.

So you could have something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!--  Style sheet references and CSS definitions -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- HTML markup and other page content -->

        <!-- JavaScript references. You could include jQuery here as well and do all your scripting here. -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may see if you are not loading jQuery twice somehow. Especially after your plugin JavaScript file loaded.

I has the same error and found that one of my external [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) files was loading jQuery again.

Answer (score 1):

The issue because of not loading jquery ui library.

https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js - CDN source file

Call above path in your file.

Comment: Could you give some more insight on how to do what you say?

Answer (score 0):

And if you have this problem in **slider or slideshow** you must use `jquery.easing.1.3`:

```
<script src="http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble getting selectable to work with [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET). It turns out I wasn't properly including everything, but this gentleman made it foolproof: *[Three steps to use jQuery UI in ASP.NET MVC 5](http://blog.falafel.com/three-steps-use-jquery-ui-asp-net-mvc-5/)*.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think jQuery itself includes datetimepicker. You must use [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) instead (src="jquery.ui").

Comment: jQuery UI implements its widgets as jQuery plugins; the posted idiom `jQuery(selector).datetimepicker()` is correct.