# Datepicker not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" name="suform" onsubmit="return validator()" action="register.php">
Date of Birth <input name="dob" type="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
</form>
</body>
```

**In .js file**

```
$(function() {$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();});
```

**and the date picker is not working in firefox and internet explorer or chrome**

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/punit1108/X9RZF/)

Comment: Can you please create JSFiddle?

Comment: I think your issue is already answered in SO.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232897/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-while-using-jquery-ui

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/punit1108/X9RZF/

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome either, even if I add JQuery as a loaded script. Chrome does render a "date" input field though.

Comment: It is working for me and i have chrome 35.0.1916.114 m.

Comment: Same here. When I click the date field, I just get the default up/down date control that Chrome renders by default when you specify type="date". I have a hard time believing your Fiddle works for you, since it'll give an error that $ and jQuery are undefined.

Comment: make sure that you have included all the jquery files propoerly.

Comment: Seems to me like you're not loading jQuery, as you only have jQueryUI in the header. Also please describe what is "not working", that's pretty vague. Anything in the console? Also you have type="date", remove that b/c HTML5 could be messing w/ the jQuery UI

Comment: Remove "id=fname" and try

Comment: Don't add jQuery's datepicker to a date input

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/X9RZF/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSFiddle has a couple of issues. For starters, your `jquery-1.10.2.js` external resource path starts with a `"`, causing a 404 when trying to load jQuery. However, that's probably not the issue you are having outside of JSFiddle.

Your main issue is that you have invalid HTML. Your datepicker elements has two `id` attributes, `fname` and `datepicker`. An HTML element can only have one `id`. Simply removing the `fname` id which you are already using above should solve your problem.

Replace:

```
<input name="dob" id="fname" type="date" id="datepicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

With:

```
<input name="dob" id="datepicker" type="date"  placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
```

**[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1g22duzx/)**

Answer (score 1):

There are two **id** given to same input element which is not valid. Remove  **id="fname"** and try.

Answer (score 0):

Chane the date of birth to this:

```
Date of Birth <input name="dob" type="text" placeholder="mm/dd/YY" id="datepicker">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/X9RZF/9/