# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datepicker

I am trying to use date picker of jquery in mvc4.

It was giving me error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

My jQuery function is like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dpFrom').datepicker();
});
```

html part is like:

```
 <input type="text" id="dpFrom"  />
```

I refered :

[Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function while using jQuery UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232897/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-while-using-jquery-ui?answertab=active#tab-top)

And included :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

So total javascript became:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#dpFrom').datepicker();

    });
</script>
```

Still its giving me error.

Please help...

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle ?

Comment: working fine for me, with the data you've provided.

Comment: I think that you have a duplicate jQuery reference. Could you open a "View Source" on your web browser and enumerate your jQuery references? It is a common error and easily missed. Maybe a bundle definition or your layout and content pages have the same reference.

Comment: @Chris -yup. there was a duplicate jQuery reference.I just comment out one.  and its working fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that you have a duplicate jQuery reference. Could you open a "View Source" on your web browser and enumerate your jQuery references? It is a common error and easily missed. Maybe a bundle definition or your layout and content pages have the same reference.

Comment: thank you - i am viewing my source, but how do I enumerate my jQuery references?

Answer (score 1):

The path should be https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js not //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js in both referencing script and css tags

Comment: Nice observation. It will be better if u suggest an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();      
</script>
```

---

I tried this one, when i erase the function().