# jQuery UI not fully working with DatePicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

[image]

The jQuery UI datepicker looks like the above but my version looks like the following.
[image]

My jQuery file is

[image]

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        /*"~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",*/
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                        //"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
                       // "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-*",

                        "~/Scripts/jquery.switchButton.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"
                        ));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/dataTables").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

I added the latest stable versions of jQuery and jQuery UI and changed the bundle config to avoid a duplication error(which is what I had to start with see   [Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function in datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26712372/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-datepicker))

[image]

One StackOverflow answer says that moment.js should be above jQuery UI but I didnt find any change, and now I'm entirely stumped as not seen jQuery UI partially work like this before.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple.. You haven't added reference to `jquery-ui.css`. Its just working fine but the `styles/CSS` aren't applied.

Get the respective version of `CSS` through the links mentioned in **[`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13314050/2065039)**