# Sending data from jQuery to controller of AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to pass data generated by jQuery into controller of AngularJS. Is there any way possible to do this.

```
 <textarea  ng-click="showSelectedText(selection.text)" name="editor1" id="editor1" cols="118" rows="35">
```

jQuery to gather Data:

```
  $( "#editor1" ).select(function() {

                var selection = getSelected()
                if(selection)
                {

                    alert(selection);
                }

                });  

                function getSelected() {
                    if (window.getSelection) {
                        return window.getSelection();
                    }
                    else if (document.getSelection) {
                        return document.getSelection();
                    }
                    else {
                        var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
                        if (selection.text) {
                            return selection.text;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                    return false;
            }
```

Controller of AngularJS:

```
 $scope.showSelectedText = function(fromUI) {

        alert("Text is : "+ fromUI);
    };
```

Comment: Do you only need to pass textarea's text in your controller ?

Comment: from text area I just need to pass the selected/highlighted text {NOT the Whole text} to the controller of AngularJs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make few changes. Like give an id to the element where you've defined your controller, like

```
<div id="demoElement" ng-app='MyModule' ng-controller="MyController">
</div>
```

In your controller remain this function same as it is. ie

```
$scope.showSelectedText = function(fromUI) {

        alert("Text is : "+ fromUI);
    };
```

Now you could remove ng-click="showSelectedText(selection.text)" from the textarea and call angular's function from your jquery code by using below line.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('demoElement')).scope().showSelectedText(jQueryObjectOfSelectedText);
```

You could call this function from your jQuery code where you're getting your selected text, like

```
  $( "#editor1" ).select(function() {

                    var selection = getSelected()
                    if(selection)
                    {
 angular.element(document.getElementById('demoElement')).scope().showSelectedText(selection);
                    }

                    });  

                    function getSelected() {
                        if (window.getSelection) {
                            return window.getSelection();
                        }
                        else if (document.getSelection) {
                            return document.getSelection();
                        }
                        else {
                            var selection = document.selection && document.selection.createRange();
                            if (selection.text) {
                                return selection.text;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                        return false;
                }
```

Comment: console shows this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSelectedText' of undefined :

Comment: Please make sure you're passing the same element in  angular.element() where your controller has defined.

Comment: with error as "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).scope is not a function"

Comment: Please check this URL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232897/uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-while-using-jquery-ui

Comment: Thankyou http://stackoverflow.com/users/4366287/vineet it really helped me to solve the problem