# How to use this angularjs method?

Tags: angularjs

angular.element.inheritedData(key)

Above method is available in angular js. This method is also mentioned in this web page. ==> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element But that does not explain how to use this method.Please give me some examples. These days I am studying angularjs. I could not find any example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30341968/sending-data-from-jquery-to-controller-of-angularjs/30342348#30342348

Comment: This is a very poor question. The title does not reflect what is being asked. Please edit, this needs to be clear to anyone reading this later on.

Comment: Both the title and the tags are important. You should include `angular.element.inheritedData(key)` in the title.

Answer (score 1):

We can fetch the data associated with an element’s $scope simply by using the inheritedData() method on the element:

```
element.inheritedData();
```

This inheritedData() finds data up the scope chain as it walks up the DOM until it’s found a particular value has been reached.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.displayForm = function(e){
    var form = angular.element(e.target)
        .inheritedData('$formController');
    $scope.form_name = form.$name;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one input text box

```
<input type="text" name="icontext">
```

now we will get this using angular.element

```
angular.element("input[name='icontext']").val();
```